# Puppeteer with Brave browser?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, brave

I'm wondering if it's possible executing a puppeteer script using Brave browser instead of the basic version of chromium. I know that Brave has been developed from chromium, and for that reason you can launch a selenium script using brave, but do you know if it's possible with puppeteer as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use Brave. The only catch is the adblocking doesn't work with headless mode. For the adblocking in *headful* mode, you need to set/create a profile and point the `userDataDir` option to it because Brave downloads the filter lists the first time it launches and stores those lists in the profile.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: "path/to/brave",
        userDataDir: "path/to/profile/dir"
});
```

Comment: @Drun edited my answer. let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: On my Mac (Sonoma 14.2.1) the executable path is: `/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser`