# Can't use Brave Browser with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation, brave

About a month ago I wrote a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482893/puppeteer-with-brave-browser) asking if it were possible using Brave Browser with puppeteer; the answer was yes, I tested it, and everything worked perfectly;
today I tried to run the same code but i got the error `ERROR: process "xxxxx" not found`

Any ideas about this issue?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async()=>{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe",
            headless:false,
            devtools:false,
        })
        const page = await browser.newPage()
})()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do at least two things to get puppeteer working with Brave.

First, you need to enable remote debugging on brave. You need to go to `chrome://settings/privacy` and then enable `Remote debugging`.

[image]

Second, Brave doesn't like many default command-line arguments that puppeteer sends. So you might want to ignore default arguments.

```js
(async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath:"/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser",
        headless:false,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: true
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    page.goto("https://www.google.com")
})()
```